# Annoying switching from a keyboard layout to another

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, 18.04

I am experiencing a bug. I am using Ubuntu <s>GNOME 17.10</s> 18.04 (see edit below), currently under Wayland (but the bug was already there a few years ago, under Xorg).

I have got two keyboard layouts enabled : Switzerland's French layout and Switzerland's German layout. Basically, there are only 3 keys which differ from another : éàè in French, and öäü in German. Note that the French layout is a variant from the German layout, which is default in Switzerland. Both are defined in the same file.

The issue is that sometimes, when the French keyboard layout is apparently selected, I am typing with the German layout (I only notice it when I use those 3 differing keys). In order to fix that, I have to switch to the German layout and back again. This does not happen every day and I am living with it for a long time.

What could be the cause ? How to fix it ?

PS : I unfortunately don't know which logs I could possibly provide. Comment that and I'll add them. Thanks in advance !!

--

Edit : **Since Ubuntu 18.04, behaviour changed : I *frequently* end up writing with the France's French AZERTY layout, which I haven't even selected or enabled.** Thus, I add the `18.04` flag to this question, that seems fair to me.

Maybe is it worth saying that Ubuntu does not support Switzerland's French language variety (why?). It only supports the Canadian and the French varieties of French, so I was always obliged to choose the France's French language. But the displaying language is supposed to have nothing to do with the choosen keyboard layout(s).
So I show you the result of the command `locale`. That may help (?)

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=fr_FR:fr_CA:en
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=fr_CH.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_CH.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fr_CH.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fr_CH.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_CH.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_CH.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_CH.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_CH.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_CH.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

--

Edit : Here are the results of following commands : `cat /etc/default/keyboard` :

```
XKBLAYOUT=ch,ch
BACKSPACE=guess
XKBVARIANT=fr,
```

and `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` :

```
[('xkb', 'ch+fr'), ('xkb', 'ch')]
```

and `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources per-window` :

```
false
```

--

**Important edit :** If I change the language of my laptop from France's French to Canadian French, keeping my Swiss layout, I end up, after a while, writing with the Canadian keyboard layout.... Even if I haven't it enabled...

Comment: The same happens to me too occasionally (have _Swedish_ and _English (US)_ enabled), and just like you I simply switch back and forth to get it right. I suppose it's a subtle desktop bug (nothing wrong with the layouts in themselves), but I'm not able to tell which package(s) is/are affected.

Comment: I have added a third layout and apparently, when I use my French QWERTZ layout (the Swiss one), I may be actually typing with another one, randomly.

Comment: Since Ubuntu 18.04, behaviour changed slightly : I frequently end up writing with the France's French AZERTY layout, which is really annoying

Comment: Please edit your question and show the output of these two commands: 1. `cat /etc/default/keyboard` 2. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson : Added. It is actually strange that my XKBVARIANT is fr.  Thank you a lot for helping me ^^

Comment: That looks correct. Another command I'd like you to run is: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources per-window`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson : It returns false, which is the default behaviour I suppose.

Comment: Yes, `false` is good. Then I'm out of ideas, I'm afraid. Hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: I've just tried to set my laptop in Canadian French, with the Swiss Layout, in order to see if instead of switching to the France's French AZERTY I switch to the Canadian's French QWERTY.... I'll post feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: .... and yes, I end up writing with the Canadian keyboard layout !!! Somebody got an idea where the bug is from ?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid switching the keyboard layout you could also search for one that can do all the characters you need and get used to that. I changed to Spanish (Latin America) layout and it can do éàè and öäü, even the ß used in Germany.

Comment: That does not help. I keep switching to the AZERTY which I haven't even enabled...